# PowerQuery Table.FromRecords not returning all columns

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

When using the Table.FromRecords function in PowerQuery the returned table does not always contain all possible columns. For example the formula below will only return a table based on the first row.

Is there a way to produce a table form records but have all possible columns returned?

```
= Table.FromRecords({
    [CustomerID = 1, Name = "Bob", Phone = "123-4567"],
    [CustomerID = 2, Name = "Jim", Phone = "987-6543"],
    [CustomerID = 3, Name = "Paul", Phone = "543-7890", Email = "hello@microsoft.com"]
  },null, MissingField.UseNull)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve the desired outcome described in the original question by writing a custom function to use instead Table.FromRecords:

```
= (columnRecords as list) =>
let 
    tableList = List.Transform(columnRecords, each Table.FromRecords({_})),
    result = Table.Combine(tableList)
in 
    result
```

Example Usage:

```
= TableFromRecords({
    [CustomerID = 1, Name = "Bob", Phone = "123-4567"],
    [CustomerID = 2, Name = "Jim", Phone = "987-6543"],
    [CustomerID = 3, Name = "Paul", Phone = "543-7890", Email = "hello@microsoft.com"]
  })
```

[image]

Comment: I learned something new! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

get the distinct names and fill in the column name parameter.  This is probably faster than expanding each record by row over a larger data set.

```
let
    Source = 
    {
      [CustomerID = 1, Name = "Bob", Phone = "123-4567"],
      [CustomerID = 2, Name = "Jim", Phone = "987-6543"],
      [CustomerID = 3, Name = "Paul", Phone = "543-7890", Email = "hello@microsoft.com"]
    },
    names = List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Source,Record.FieldNames))),
    tbl= Table.FromRecords(Source,names,MissingField.UseNull)
in
    tbl
```

Comment: I haven't tested this out but I intuitively agree. In order for a table to be presented, even the first row of a table, it has to know the column names and count. Also power query is extremely efficient (i.e. lazy). For example, `List.FirstN(List.Repeat({1}, n))` takes the same amount of time whether `n` is 20 or two million because `List.Repeat` generates each element of the list *only on demand*. I would expect performance for `Table.FirstN(Table.FromRecords(List.Repeat({[a=1,b=2]}, n), type table [a=number, b=number]), 10)` to act the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Columns` argument to define all the fields and also set the Column Types. For example:

```
Table.FromRecords({
    [CustomerID = 1, Name = "Bob", Phone = "123-4567"],
    [CustomerID = 2, Name = "Jim", Phone = "987-6543"],
    [CustomerID = 3, Name = "Paul", Phone = "543-7890", Email = "hello@microsoft.com"]},
    type table[CustomerID=nullable text, Name=nullable text, Email=nullable text], MissingField.UseNull)
```

[image]

Or, if you don't care about defining the column types within the `Table.FromRecords` function:

```
Table.FromRecords({
    [CustomerID = 1, Name = "Bob", Phone = "123-4567"],
    [CustomerID = 2, Name = "Jim", Phone = "987-6543"],
    [CustomerID = 3, Name = "Paul", Phone = "543-7890", Email = "hello@microsoft.com"]},
    {"CustomerID","Name", "Email"}, MissingField.UseNull)
```

[image]